# Rinkeby Transactions not getting mined

Tags: mining, rinkeby, pending-transactions, proof-of-authority

I am trying to send transaction to a contract, but my transactions is not getting mined. For troubleshooting, I tried various gas prices, with same nonce:

- [25 wei (0.000000025 Gwei)](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x77e359adea28b9fd8c474beebe668000b0c8e2d8049b11c6188d96d623973e91)
- [22 wei (0.000000022 Gwei)](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x0e1c87e000fa4ebd95d379f0c22962595ec7348800304ff438d38a0642a204cf)
- [20 wei (0.00000002 Gwei)](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x55eea2d4aaa10cb4aba3c0c19cbbf44011d1301e054196eea61ab5e1674311e7)
- [10 wei (0.00000001 Gwei)](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xea04bdd332cfcd982bd24abcd6738c50b36262c454e8f0212f91faf3616103be)

But none of them are getting mined. I am expecting transaction to return a status, either `success` or a `failure`, but they remain pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gas prices are much too cheap; If you look at transactions that are getting mined on Rinkeby, they're typically in the 1 Gwei to 25 Gwei range. So try a more generous gas price.

BTW you don't need to increase the gas *limit* - this makes it less likely your transaction will be mined, because if there are other more profitable transactions, it becomes impossible to fit yours in the same block as them.